# How to install Beatbox Music Player in ubuntu 14.4 LTS

Tags: 14.04

How to install Beatbox Music Player in ubuntu 14.4 LTS ? I have tried a lot most of the sites i have seen it supports till 12.04 ?

And which music player is similar to Beatbox Music player ? Noise player ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The developer of Beatbox ended the software somewhere in 2013 due to a lack of time. The last release was "saucy" (13.10). If you want you can add the 13.10 PPA to your system by adding ...

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/sgringwe/beatbox/ubuntu saucy main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/sgringwe/beatbox/ubuntu saucy main
```

to your sources. And from command line of from Ubuntu software center you can install this older version. Command line:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install beatbox.
```

But Noise Music Player is indeed the to go to music player if you want an alternative. Installation of NMP can be done by adding in a PPA and install it from there (this will install the latest newest version) (command line version):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install noise
```